# NET CORE Json Model Binding to Save EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to the whole concept, so sorry for my noobieness.

I have a .NET Core Web API with 2 models, OrganizationEntity and PersonEntity:

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public OrganizationEntity Organization { get; set; }
}


public class OrganizationEntity 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TradeName { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonEntity> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Which means that it is a one-to-many relationship.

Testing in Postman I send:

```
{
  "Name": "Organization1",
  "TradeName": "Org",
  "Telephone": "321565432",
  "Persons" : [
      {
          "Name": "John Smith",
      }
  ]
}
```

EF saves the two entities with the foreign key in persons table correctly. But if the person already exists in the database, and the guid is sent to the controller like this:

```
{
  "Name": "Organization1",
  "TradeName": "Org",
  "Telephone": "321565432",
  "Persons" : [
    {
        "Id": "e573eb0e-5975-46c2-a0ee-c1e505c9c0ab"    
    }
  ]
}
```

It saves the organization entity and returns an error.

How should I treat this kind of situation? Should I send the contacts to be related to the organization in another JSON key to be included manually to the organization instance and then saved? Is there any material that has this kind of answers that I could read? I tried searching for it in Google, but didn't find anything.

Comment: could you add the `error` to the question!

Comment: The idea that postman data maps directly to your database is bad design.  I realise all the MS examples do this, but it's not good practice.  You should look at view model-> DTO -> Entity to give you full control over what (and how) entities are written to your database.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PersonEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

If I change to "PersonId": "e573eb0...", it says that order fields that are required cannot be null